# C++ unexpected garbage values when printing variables

Tags: c++

this code :

```
int a[] = {};
    int i,b,o,p,j;
    std::cout<<"a[-2] >> "<<a[-2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"a[-1] >> "<<a[-1]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"a[0] >> "<<a[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"a[1] >> "<<a[1]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"a[2] >> "<<a[2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"b >> "<<b<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"p >> "<<p<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"j >> "<<j<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"a[3] >> "<<a[3]<<std::endl;
```

output like this.. :

```
a[-2] >> -875679664
a[-1] >> -2
a[0] >> 7470856
a[1] >> 1993175021
.
.
j >> 7470856
a[3] >> 7470928
```

help me please, i don't really known

thanks..
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: What did you expect? Your program has undefined behavior since you read uninitialized variables.

Comment: Why did you tag it as `C`? The code is without a doubt not C.

Comment: Two words: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Compiler is allowed to do anything with this code, even make [demons fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: `int a[] = {};` no index of a is valid.

Comment: `int a[] = {};` is an array of `0` elements, at least that's what the compiler says: https://godbolt.org/z/oE1Yx8